# Translating Vector in R

Tags: r, vector

If I have a vector that looks like the following:

```
vec1 <- c(4, 4, 5, 1, 23, 7, 8)
```

I want to translate this to a vector from 1:length(vec1) so that it looks like this:

```
vec2 <- c(2,2,3,1,6,4,5)
```

vec2 is a translated version of vec1, where the elements are from 1 to 6 based on the ordering of elements in vec2. Is there a function in base-R to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `min_rank()` in `library(dplyr)`

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

vec1 <- c(4, 4, 5, 1, 23, 7, 8)

dense_rank(vec1)
#> [1] 2 2 3 1 6 4 5

# or

min_rank(vec1)
#> [1] 2 2 4 1 7 5 6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>